# Installing Bioconductor packages yields 404 errors

Tags: r, bioconductor

running `BiocManager::install("curatedMetagenomicData", force = TRUE)` (and any other BiocManager installation) yields the following. Please note the line that starts with "Warning: downloaded length 0".
The packages that I am attempting to install are not usable after running this command.

```
> BiocManager::install("curatedMetagenomicData", force = TRUE)
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see 'help("repositories", package = "BiocManager")' for details.
Replacement repositories:
    BioCsoft: https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/bioc
    BioCann: https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/data/annotation
    BioCexp: https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/data/experiment
    BioCworkflows: https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/workflows
    BioCbooks: https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/books
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/
Bioconductor version 3.17 (BiocManager 1.30.21), R 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Installing package(s) 'curatedMetagenomicData'
Warning: downloaded length 0 != reported length 0Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/data/annotation/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Warning: downloaded length 194903671234147059908680621327167218372650254296316823542298890145040407740976146835136608033272397067763817676906493076547814582096137001271025369370370560141537882572770034043291945833017878348420694053401505275688319191089152 != reported length 0Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/data/annotation/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Warning: downloaded length 0 != reported length 0Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/data/experiment/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Warning: downloaded length 0 != reported length 0Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/data/experiment/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Warning: downloaded length 0 != reported length 0Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/workflows/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Warning: downloaded length 194903671234147059908680621327167218372650254296316823542298890145040407740976146835136608033272397067763817676906493076547814582096137001271025369370370560141537882572770034043291945833017878348420694053401505275688319191089152 != reported length 0Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/workflows/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Warning: downloaded length 0 != reported length 0Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/books/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Warning: downloaded length 194903671234147059908680621327167218372650254296316823542298890145040407740976146835136608033272397067763817676906493076547814582096137001271025369370370560141537882572770034043291945833017878348420694053401505275688319191089152 != reported length 0Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/books/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'installing the source package ‘curatedMetagenomicData’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/data/experiment/src/contrib/curatedMetagenomicData_3.8.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1932166 bytes (1.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.8 MB

* installing *source* package ‘curatedMetagenomicData’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (curatedMetagenomicData)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/0y/dc3r6c6d1vb3v7dbw97hbl800000gn/T/RtmpsagCQQ/downloaded_packages’
```

My setup:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.7.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BiocManager_1.30.21 Biobase_2.60.0      BiocGenerics_0.46.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1 tools_4.3.1    curl_5.0.1     remotes_2.4.2  knitr_1.43     xfun_0.39
```

I have confirmed that the network is working as I am able to read the bioconductor config using readlines(). I am not clear on why there would be these 404 errors.
I am on an intel mac, and using a fresh install of R via RStudio.

Comment: Looks to me that there was an encoded workaround to a missing URL and that there were no errors of importance. What errors are you seeing? (eventually you will probably learn that in R console informative displays that "warnings" are generally of lesser significance than ERRORs which will usually be displayed in Red.)